# What i need to do with array? Ruby

Tags: ruby

If you are given an array of undetermined length with numbers in random

order. Please write a method to return the minimum # of elements that add

up to a number >= X (where X is an input to the method? (e.g. array = [1,4,3,2],

X = 6, answer is 2 elements: 4 + 3)

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't exist to do your homework for you. If you need help with a homework question, please provide (at a minimum) an explanation of what you've tried and what you're stuck on or the error you're getting.

Comment: You should read, [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def solution(arr, x)
  sum = 0
  arr.sort.reverse.each_with_index do |e, i|
    sum = sum + e
    return i+1 if sum >= x
  end
  return nil
end
```

Given and array `arr = [1,4,3,2]`, `arr.sort` gives `[1,2,3,4]`. Just reverse the array and accumulate the elements until the accumulator >= X. Since the array is reverse sorted, we are adding the largest element of the array to the accumulator with each iteration. Here I return `i+1` since arrays are zero-indexed and we want the number of elements we've added so far.